# Print number of ways for non-consecutive one's

Tags: python, c, algorithm, recursion

Given a positive integer N, print all integers between 1 and 2^N such that there is no consecutive 1’s in its Binary representation.

I have below code but it is printing duplicate sometimes. Is it possible to print without duplicates?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[100];
void foo(int i, int size)
{
    if (i >= size) {
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<size;i++)
            printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        printf("----\n");
        return;
    }

    if (a[i-1] == 1 || a[i-1] == 0)
        a[i] = 0;
    foo(i+1, size);
    if (a[i-1] == 0)
        a[i] = 1;   
    foo(i+1, size);
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int size = 5;
    a[i] = 1;
    foo(1, size);
    return 0;
}
```

I have this http://ideone.com/cT4Hco python program which uses hash maps to print the elements but I think we can do this without hashmaps also.

Comment: The logic seems rather muddled, e.g. what is `if (a[i-1] == 1 || a[i-1] == 0)` supposed to test for ?

Comment: What language is this? it looks like `C` but I do not want to assume anything.

Comment: @PaulR: We can set the current index 0 in the case previous element is 1 or 0, that is the logic there.

Comment: @JohnOdom: Code is given in C along with python link.

Comment: @nomanpouigt: aren't *all* the values either 0 or 1 though ? Or is there some other value that you are trying to store in the elements of `a[]` ?

Comment: I think the last if in `foo` should apply to the next two statements, not just the next one.

Comment: You always call `foo` twice from within itself, is this really what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of notes:

- you shouldn't start the backtracking from index 1. Instead, start from 0 since your numbers would be in the range `[0, n-1]` in array `a`
- you shouldn't initialize `a[0]` to `1` since `a[0] = 0` is also a valid case.
- `if (a[i-1] == 1 || a[i-1] == 0)` is redundant

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[100];
void foo(int i, int size)
{
    if (i >= size) {
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<size;i++)
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        printf("\n----\n");
        return;
    }

    a[i] = 0;
    foo(i+1, size);
    if ( i == 0 || a[i-1] == 0) {
        a[i] = 1;
        foo(i+1, size);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int size = 5;
    foo(0, size);
    return 0;
}
```

You might also want to filter the solution `0 0 0 ... 0` during the printing since you need only the numbers from `1` to `2^n`. If `2^n` is included you should also print it. The backtracking considers the numbers `0, ...., 2^n-1`